# Autocad Civil Surface creation problem

Tags: autocad

I'm trying to create a new surface in Autocad Civil 2012. I have elevations for a landfill, and it seems like I'm following all the correct steps. But when I check the surface out under Surface Properties/Statistics, it appears the X,Y & Z coordinates have been scaled down by 3 decimal places. I'm using UTM coordinates to create the points.

Example:

Min elevation = 0.071m 
Min X = 481.510m 
etc.

Any help greatly appreciated!

-jason m.

Comment: try to output a raster. I could be wrong but I think Civil is just "showing" 3 decimals. the actual data should still contain the full field setting.

Comment: or do a cross section and output the text.